# For each value in column A, how can I incrementally create 9 URLS in column BC with the value from column A appended to the end?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-formula, shopify

I have the following Excel spreadsheet where

- Row 1 is the header row;
- Column A is any string; and
- Column B is an empty string.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **ID** | **Image Src** |
| **2** | aa |  |
| **3** | ab |  |
| **4** | ac |  |
| **5** | ad |  |

My macro below is supposed to take the value in cell A2 ('aa'), append it to a URL ('https://test.com/**aa**'), and then append a number ranging from 1 to 9 followed by the string '.webp'. An example output would be 'https://test.com/aa-1.webp'.

For every string in column A, it should be duplicated 9 times. In addition, each duplicated value will be accompanied by a sequential URL in column B (see table for example).

**The Problem:**

*The desired output:*

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **ID** | **Image Src** |
| **2** | aa | https://test.com/aa-1.webp |
| **3** | aa | https://test.com/aa-2.webp |
| ... | ... | ... |
| **10** | aa | https://test.com/aa-9.webp |
| **11** | ab | https:// test.com/ab-1.webp |
| ... | ... | ... |

*What the macro instead produces:*

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **ID** | **Image Src** |
| **2** | aa |  |
| **3** | ab | https://test.com/aa-1.webp |
| **4** |  | https://test.com/aa-2.webp |
| ... | ... | ... |
| **11** |  | https://test.com/aa-9.webp |
| **12** |  | https://test.com/ab-1.webp |
| ... | ... | ... |

[Link to screenshot of spreadsheet showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6ZF9.png)

- The macro successfully creates 9 URLs sequentially in column B, but it starts in cell B3 instead of B2.
- The macro needlessly leaves B2 entirely blank.
- The macro leaves the IDs in column A entirely untouched. In my example, you can see that each URL in column B is supposed to be paired with its corresponding value from column A.

**What I've attempted so far:**

```
Sub DuplicateCellsAndGenerateURLs()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Set the range of the source data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' This line will find the last row
    Set sourceRange = Range("A2:A" & lastRow) ' Define the source range
    
    ' Set the destination range in column A and B
    Set destinationRange = Range("A2:B" & (lastRow * 9) + 1) ' Adjust the destination range
    
    ' Duplicate values in column A
    sourceRange.Copy destinationRange.Columns(1)
    
    ' Generate URLs in column B
    i = 2 ' Start index for URL generation
    For Each cell In sourceRange
        If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For ' Stop if an empty cell is encountered in column A
        For j = 0 To 8
            destinationRange.Cells(i + j, "B").Value = "https://test.com" & cell.Value & "-" & j + 1 & ".webp"
        Next j
        i = i + 9 ' Increment index for next URL generation block
    Next cell
End Sub
```

***TL;DR: string 'aa' should occupy A2:A10; 'https://test.com/aa-#.webp' should occupy B2:B10; repeat for each value in column A ('ab', 'ac', 'ad', etc).***

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to understand your question if you simplify: use example strings "aa" and "bb" instead of the long numbers. Use `https://test.com/aa-1.webp` instead of a long and complex URL, and **point out what the problem is**. Also, please don't use an image to display a table. Use plain text, explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is that you are overwriting your `sourceRange` (column A) at the same time as you want to get information from it. `sourceRange` will be updated when you do your loop, since it's a `range()`. Therefore we loose the initial data values.

One way to solve this is to store `sourceRange` values temporary, in another column.

Another is to store your values in a array so you prevent overwriting the "source data". Array is not updated if you don't explicitly command it to.

```
Sub DuplicateCellsAndGenerateURLs2()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    Dim lrow_bc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant
    
    ' Set the range of the source data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' This line will find the last row
    myArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A" & lastRow)) ' Define the ID's to be store in an array
    
    j = 1 'set the intial array value (which array number loop should start from)
    For Each myCell In myArr 'Loop through the array
        If IsEmpty(myCell) Then Exit For ' Stop if an empty cell is encountered in the array (from column A)
            lrow_bc = Cells(Rows.Count, "BC").End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row for the URL destination, update it for every ID
            For k = 1 To 9
                Cells(lrow_bc + k, "BC").Value = "https://exampleimagesource.blob.core.windows.net/inventory/" & myArr(j) & "-" & k & ".webp" 'To get Array number, use myArr(j)
            Next k
            Range("A" & lrow_bc + 1 & ":" & "A" & lrow_bc + 9).Value = myArr(j) 'Populate the ID by nine rows each time.
            j = j + 1 'update array iteration number
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You're a saint. This entirely fixed my issue. Thank you so much for your effort and time - this had stumped me for days.

Comment: Glad it helped you :). A bit tricky to figure out how to use column A and also write the new values to it, but was fun challenge (I thou recommend to use dummy column if you use `range()`). And I think your first version of the question was more than good enough =). Plenty of valuable information to solve this issue :).